# Why after enable macOS Proxy in Charles Proxy internet traffic is not working on MacOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, proxy, port, charles-proxy

I have made the installation steps for Charles proxy:

1. Installed Charles soft to MacOS Ventura;
2. Installed Charles Root Sertificate;
3. Add Charles Sertificate and enabled Trust Always;
4. Installed Charles sertificate to IOS simulator and activated it;
5. Enabled SSL Proxying in Proxy => SSL Proxying and added star for host and port:

[image]

And after I enabled macOS Proxy in Charles, started to get traffic in Structure tab, but there is no internet connection. Moreover I tried to set server and port value in Mac system settings Proxies accordingly Charles documentation https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/ and when I have enabled it the internet connection has gone again.
Can you tell me please what I'm doing wrong? What's more should I set to launch Charles?
[image]